# Touchenter and touchleave events support

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-applications

I read about touchenter and touchleave events, at  [mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) and [w3 website](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/#the-touchenter-event), but can not find any browser to support it or any javascript library that mimics that effect.

Please suggest what could be done as there workaround, as I am working for some mouseover like effect , event gets triggered when fingers enter the element, not when user lifts and touches elements again.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suggest that you use

`document.elementFromPoint(touch.x, touch.y);`

on touchmove event.

Comment: $('#container,#button1').on('swipeUp',function(e) {...});

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. However missing the important thing, the how-to it self

Answer (score 11):

You're referencing an [old draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/), [the latest one removed the touchenter and touchleave events](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#list-of-touchevent-types).

Answer (score 1):

There is a list [here](http://caniuse.com/touch) stating the version-wise compatibility. Currently Chrome, Opera, iOS Safari, Android Browser, Blackberry Browser, Opera Mobile, Chrome for Android, Firefox for android support this feature

Answer (score 1):

W3C removed ontouchenter and ontouchleave, so that we can only do these(with zepto.js, touch.js, ontouchmove, elementFromPoint):

```
var last_touched_button='';
$('#container,#button1,#button2').on('touchmove',function(e){
      var ele=document.elementFromPoint(e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY);
      if (ele==document.getElementById('button1'))
      {last_touched_button='button1';
      }
      else if (ele==document.getElementById('button2'))
      {last_touched_button='button2';
      }
});
$('#container,#button1,#button2').on('swipeLeft',function(e){
      console.log('the button '+last_touched_button+' triggered swipe_into_left_side event or swipe_out_from_left_side event!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Currently, there is no support for such events at core**, however it is possible to simulate them.

I Created a small script to make **onTouchEnter** and **onTouchLeave** methods available. Very simple use
(To test the snippet **activate the mobile version** of this website, or use it at a smartphone browser)

```js
onTouchEnter('.some-selector', function(element,event){/*DO ANYTHING*/})
onTouchLeave('.some-selector', function(element,event){/*DO ANYTHING*/})
```

The script bellow uses *document.elementFromPoint* to make the magic.

```js
let onTouchLeaveEvents = [];
let onTouchEnterEvents = [];
const onTouchEnter = function (selector, fn) {
    onTouchEnterEvents.push([selector, fn]);
    return function () {
        onTouchEnterEvents.slice().map(function (e, i) {
            if (e[0] === selector && e[1] === fn) {
                onTouchEnterEvents.splice(1, i);
            }
        });
    };
};

const onTouchLeave = function (selector, fn) {
    onTouchLeaveEvents.push([selector, fn]);
    return function () {
        onTouchLeaveEvents.slice().map(function (e, i) {
            if (e[0] === selector && e[1] === fn) {
                onTouchLeaveEvents.splice(1, i);
            }
        });
    };
};

let lastTouchLeave;
let lastTouchEnter;
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    var el = document.elementFromPoint(e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY);
    if (!el) return;
  
  onTouchLeaveEvents.map((event) => {
    if (el!=lastTouchEnter && lastTouchEnter && lastTouchEnter.matches(event[0])) {
      
        
            if (lastTouchEnter !== lastTouchLeave ) {
                event[1](lastTouchEnter, e);
        lastTouchLeave = lastTouchEnter;
        lastTouchEnter = null
            }
            
        }
    });
  
    onTouchEnterEvents.map((event) => {
        if (el.matches(event[0]) && el!==lastTouchEnter) {
            lastTouchEnter = el;
      lastTouchLeave = null;
      event[1](el, e);
     }
    });

});

onTouchEnter('.area',function(el,e){
  el.classList.add('hover')
})
onTouchLeave('.area',function(el,e){
  el.classList.remove('hover')
})
```

```css
.area {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:2px ;
  font-size:12px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  float:left;
}
.area.hover{
  background-color:#333 !important;
  color:#fff;
}
#div-1{background-color:#f00;}
#div-2{background-color:#0f0;}
#div-3{background-color:#00f;}
body{
overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1" class="area">DIV 1</div>
<div id="div-2" class="area">DIV 2</div>
<div id="div-3" class="area">DIV 3</div>
```

[This GIST](https://gist.github.com/zerobytes/677410f1e6ed33d133aa016422a8c706) contains the same code as above, for improvements, please create comments there.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. In callbacks I just need the element; not the mouse/touch event and not the context (don't use 'this' in callback).

pointer.ts

```
/**
 *  Simulate touchenter and touchleave by tracking touchmove. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111671/touchenter-and-touchleave-events-support
 */
const touchEventSimulator = {

    // enterElementCallback stores element as key and callback as value
    enterElementCallback: new Map(),
    leaveElementCallback: new Map(),
    previousElement: null,

    init: function() {
        window.addEventListener('touchmove', event => {
            var currentElement = document.elementFromPoint(event.touches[0].clientX, event.touches[0].clientY)
            if (currentElement !== this.previousElement) {

                // touch leave
                const leaveCallback = this.leaveElementCallback.get(this.previousElement)
                if (leaveCallback) {
                    leaveCallback.call(null, this.previousElement)
                }

                // touch enter
                const enterCallback = this.enterElementCallback.get(currentElement)
                if (enterCallback) {
                    enterCallback.call(null, currentElement)
                }

                // Current element will be the previous one, next time we check.
                this.previousElement = currentElement;
            }
        });
    },
    onEnter(element, callback) {
        this.enterElementCallback.set(element, callback);
    },
    onLeave(element, callback) {
        this.leaveElementCallback.set(element, callback);
    }
}

const mouseAvailable = matchMedia('(pointer:fine)').matches;

/**
 * Pointer is a wrapper for mouse and (simulated) touch events
 */
export const pointer = {
    mouseAvailable,

    init() {
        if (!mouseAvailable) {
            touchEventSimulator.init()
        }
    },

    onEnter: (element, callback) => {
        if (mouseAvailable) {
            element.addEventListener('mouseenter', ()=>callback.call(null, element))
        } else {
            touchEventSimulator.onEnter(element, callback)
        }
    },

    onLeave: (element, callback) => {
        if (mouseAvailable) {
            element.addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=>callback.call(null, element))
        } else {
            touchEventSimulator.onLeave(element, callback)
        }
    }
}
```

example.ts

```
import {pointer} from './pointer';

pointer.init();
const element = document.getElementById('test');
pointer.onEnter(anchor, element=>{
    console.log('enter', element)
})

pointer.onLeave(anchor, element=>{
    console.log('leave', element)
})
```